# CWSIA0112E: The property name Keep-Alive is not a valid Java identifier

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-integration, outbound

I see tonnes of logs for all header properties that have  hyphen -

> [30-5-18 17:13:14:321 CEST] 00001622 SystemOut     O WARN
>   [integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper] failed to map Message header
>   'Keep-Alive' to JMS property javax.jms.MessageFormatException:
>   CWSIA0112E: The property name Keep-Alive is not a valid Java
>   identifier.
>
> [30-5-18 17:13:14:321 CEST] 00001622 SystemOut     O WARN
>   [integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper] failed to map Message header
>   'Transfer-Encoding' to JMS property javax.jms.MessageFormatException:
>   CWSIA0112E: The property name Transfer-Encoding is not a valid Java
>   identifier.

How can I resolve all these errors and warnings
Does a custom header mapper help, any example?
Using Spring boot 1.4.3 and integration version 4.3.6. Application running on websphere default JMS provider 8.5.x

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the error means that you can't use dash in the property name.

You need to re-map this `Keep-Alive` into something like `KeepAlive` using `HeaderEnricher` and then remove it using `HeaderFilter`.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Can you please give an example. I think the issue is because of differences betwen spring jms and java jms. Some are like jms_type and other is JMSType kind of format

Comment: There is no issue with Spring JMS, because it is just a Spring API around standard Java JMS. The issue with the IBM JMS vendor. I believe it just doesn't like a dash (`-`) symbol in that `Keep-Alive` name. That's why I suggest you to re-map it to something other or just drop it off, if you are fine to live without it in downstream.

Comment: ok. Thanks Artem. added a new channel. <int:header-filter input-channel="headerFilterChannel" header-names="Api-Key, Content-Type, X-Powered-By, Content-Language, Transfer-Encoding, Cache-Control, Keep-Alive, Set-Cookie" output-channel="dest-channel" />